# Why do we choose $|l - m| \over 2$ as $\epsilon$ in this proof of the Uniqueness of a Limit?

Tags: calculus, analysis, epsilon-delta

> **Theorem 1** - Let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $X \subset \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ approaches $l$ near $a$, and $f$ approaches m near a, then $l = m$.

*This is from Spivak Calculus, 4e.*

I have seen similar question relating to the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889547/the-uniqueness-of-a-limit-of-a-function-spivaks-proof), where it was asked why we choose $\delta = min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$.

The question remains, why do we choose $|l-m| \over 2$ as our $\epsilon$? I understand that we need to choose an $\epsilon$ to show the falsehood of the statement if we assume $l$ does not equal $m$.

The online version of the textbook is [here](https://notendur.hi.is/mbh6/html/_downloads/Calculus%20-%20Michael%20Spivak.pdf). The proof can be found by inputting pages 112-113 in the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the aim is to get $$|l-m|\leq\tfrac12\,|l-m|,$$ thus showing that $l-m=0$. The $\tfrac12$ is irrelevant, any other $t\in(0,1)$ would do.

Comment: Is this because we are showing a contradiction and $|l - m|$ cannot be less than $1 \over 2$ of itself?

Comment: There's no need to think about contradictions. The number $|l-m|$ satisfies the inequality. The only number satisfying that inequality is zero.

Comment: The dissociation was that I wasn't thinking of $|l-m|$ as a number. Thanks for the clarity!!

Comment: Actually, I believe the contradiction is that we get $|\ell - m|<2\dfrac{|\ell-m|}2$.

Comment: @Ted: yes, that depends on how you set up the proof, I guess. If you start with $\varepsilon=|l-m|/2$, then I think one has to go for the contradiction. If instead you take something like $|l-m|/3$, then you get an inequality like $|l-m|\leq 2|l-m|/3$ which allows you to deduce that $|l-m|=0$ directly without appealing to a contradiction argument.

Comment: @Martin Argerami. But how would you combine two inequalities if you considert hem over different intervals? Inequalities can be combined only when they are considered over the same interval.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose both limits exist and that they are different. Thus, given $\epsilon > 0$, there are $\delta_{1} > 0$ and $\delta_{2} > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
0 < |x - a| < \delta_{1}\\\\
0 < |x - a| < \delta_{2}
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow
\begin{cases}
|f(x) - m| < \epsilon\\\\
|f(x) - l| < \epsilon
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Hence, if we take $\delta = \min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$ and $\displaystyle \epsilon = \frac{|l - m|}{2}$, we get the following contradiction:
\begin{align*}
0 < |x - a| < \delta \Longrightarrow |l - m| \leq |f(x) - l| + |f(x) - m| < 2\epsilon = |l - m|
\end{align*}

which concludes the proof. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is it necessary to show that $|l-m| < |l-m|$? Is it because this is a contradiction that $|l-m|$ cannot be strictly less than itself?

Comment: That's the point. We have shown that $0 < 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: This makes so much sense now!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two inequalities here corresponding to the two limits $l$ and $m$. These inequalities can be combined only when they are considered over the same interval(both on the x-axis and the y-axis). And the only way one can do that is by considering an interval of size $|l-m| \over 2$.